# How to make Shiro return 403 Forbidden with Spring Boot rather than redirect to login.jsp

Tags: java, spring-boot, shiro

I have a server that is just an API endpoint, no client front-end, no jsp, no html. It uses Spring Boot and I'm trying to secure it with Shiro. The relevent parts of my SpringBootServletInitializer look like this. I'm trying to get Shiro to return a 403 response if it fails the roles lookup as defined in BasicRealm. Yet it seems to default to redirecting to a non-existent login.jsp and no matter what solution I seem to use. I can't override that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    ...

    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();


        Map<String, String> filterChain = new HashMap<>();
        filterChain.put("/admin/**", "roles[admin]");

        shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChain);
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());

        return shiroFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(userRealm());

        CookieRememberMeManager rmm = new CookieRememberMeManager();
        rmm.setCipherKey(Base64.decode("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
        securityManager.setRememberMeManager(rmm);

        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "userRealm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public BasicRealm userRealm() {
        return new BasicRealm();
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}

public class BasicRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    private static Logger logger = UserService.logger;
    private static final String REALM_NAME = "BASIC";

    public BasicRealm() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(final AuthenticationToken token)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        String userid = upToken.getUsername();

        User user = Global.INST.getUserService().getUserById(userid);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [" + userid + "]");
        }

        return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(userid, user.getHashedPass().toCharArray(), REALM_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(final PrincipalCollection principals) {

        String userid = (String) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal();

        if (userid == null) {
            return new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        }

        return new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(Global.INST.getUserService().getRoles(userid));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is how I solved it. I created a class ...

```
public class AuthFilter extends RolesAuthorizationFilter {
    private static final String MESSAGE = "Access denied.";

    @Override
    protected boolean onAccessDenied(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse ;
        try {
            httpResponse = WebUtils.toHttp(response);
        }
        catch (ClassCastException ex) {
            // Not a HTTP Servlet operation
            return super.onAccessDenied(request, response) ;
        }

        if (MESSAGE == null) {
            httpResponse.sendError(403);
        } else {
            httpResponse.sendError(403, MESSAGE);
        }
        return false;  // No further processing.
    }
}
```

... and then in my shiroFilter() method above I added this code ...

```
Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
filters.put("roles", new AuthFilter());
shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);
```

... hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In Shiro 1.4+ you can set the login url in your application.properties:

https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/samples/spring-boot-web/src/main/resources/application.properties#L20

Earlier versions you should be able to set `ShiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login")`

https://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/spring/web/ShiroFilterFactoryBean.html